# How to extend an ember-cli addon?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

In my ember-cli app i have installed an addon called `'ember-cli-selectize'`. Looking at the directory structure i can see that its files are located at `/node_modules/ember-cli-selectize'`. Now i want to create a custom component that extends this addon. How do i import/require it? I've tried these and none seems to work:

`var EmberSelectize = require('/ember-cli-selectize/app/components/ember-selectize');`

`import EmberSelectize from 'components/ember-selectize';`

`import EmberSelectize from 'node_modules/ember-cli-selectize/addon/components/ember-selectize';`

`import EmberSelectize from 'ember-cli-selectize/addon/components/ember-selectize';`

i always get this 'Could not find module' error no matter what. I need to somehow import/require it to do something like

```
import EmberSelectize from 'wherever/it/is';
export default EmberSelectize.extend({
  //my own customizations
})
```

Comment: are you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You were close with:

```
import EmberSelectize from 'components/ember-selectize';
```

Addons namespace themselves - in this case, ember-cli-selectize. So, just add the namespace to your import:

```
import EmberSelectizeComponent from 'ember-cli-selectize/components/ember-selectize';
```

then you can extend:

```
export default EmberSelectizeComponent.extend({ });
```