# Ember.js how to extend ember-cli-addon component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, stripe-connect

I'm using Stripe in my Ember app, and I've set it up following the instructions here :
https://github.com/sweettooth/ember-cli-stripe

so as my app stands right now, the ember-checkout component installed via this addon is in

myappname/node_modules/ember-cli-stripe/app/components/stripe-checkout

Now, I want to create a new component "my-stripe-checkout", and have it extend the default ember-cli-stripe component.

I have tried:

```
import StripeCheckoutComponent from '../node_modules/ember-cli-stripe/app/components/stripe-checkout';
import StripeCheckoutComponent from 'ember-cli-stripe/app/components/stripe-checkout';
import StripeCheckoutComponent from 'app/components/stripe-checkout';
```

in my my-stripe-checkout component that I generated via Ember g, but to no avail.

I always get an error of this pattern:

```
Could not find module `app/components/stripe-checkout` imported from `myappname/components/my-stripe-checkout`
```

And as per this question:
[How to extend an ember-cli addon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654662/how-to-extend-an-ember-cli-addon)

I tried doing

```
import StripeCheckoutComponent from 'ember-cli-stripe/components/stripe-checkout';
```

but same error.

I've also tried both :

```
export default Ember.StripeCheckoutComponent.extend({ })
```

and

```
export default StripeCheckoutComponent.extend({})
```

to each iteration of the imports, but nothing seems to work. How do I extend an ember-cli-addon component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to understand that the `app` directory of an addon is directly merged with your app structure. Its best practice to keep all code in the `addon` directory, however `ember-cli-stripe` hasn't done this. So from inside of your `components` directory you basically can do

```
import StripeCheckoutComponent from './stripe-checkout';
```

or

```
import StripeCheckoutComponent from 'YourAppName/components/stripe-checkout';
```

If the component would be in the `addon` directory of the addon the correct way would be:

```
import StripeCheckoutComponent from 'ember-cli-stripe/components/stripe-checkout';
```

Comment: Illumination indeed. So what I was missing is that because this particular addon's structure is different, I wasn't referencing the right path. I wasn't a hundred percent sure where the add-ons were merged. Thanks very much!!