# Ember: Add attribute to element generated by helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following template file:

```
<h2 style="margin-top: 20px" class="ui header">{{t 'Unscheduled Sessions'}}</h2>
<div id="sessions-list">
  {{#each unscheduled as |session|}}
    {{#draggable-object content=session}}
      <div class="unscheduled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" data-placement="top" draggable="true">
        <span class="text">
          {{session.title}} | 
        </span>
        {{#each session.speakers as |speaker|}}
          <span class="text speaker">
            {{speaker.name}}
          </span>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    {{/draggable-object}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I want to add a `data` attribute to the elements generated by the `{{draggable object ...}}` helper. This attribute should essentially have its value as `session`, and it's not the same as `content`. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is draggable-object a component you control? Does this help? https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-attributes

Comment: @handlebears It is a third party helper. I want to add `data-*` attributes to it but am unable to.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can import and extend the addon component, as described here https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/customizing-a-components-element/

Comment: @handlebears Trying that for almost 5 hours :(

Comment: That sounds frustrating. What’s the issue you are hitting? I’ve never tried this myself but maybe someone else can chime in

Comment: @handlebears I have a list of events which I want to drag to a calendar, but the calendar will only recognize them if they have an `event` data. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom data-* attribiute to an existing addon's components, first you need to import the component, extend it to include the data-* attribute, and then use your extended component in your app.

Generate your own component, let's say `data-draggable`, and put something like this in the component JS. Here, we're importing the component from the addon `ember-drag-drop`, and then adding our own `attributeBindings` features to it, which is necessary for custom element properties.

```
import Component from 'ember-drag-drop/components/draggable-object';

export default Component.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['data-event']
});
```

Then you can use your extended component in your template, instead of the addon component directly:

```
{{#data-draggable content=this data-event="some data thing"}}
   some stuff
{{/data-draggable}}
```

You should see the `data-event="some data thing"` attribute on the resulting markup.

See the Guides for adding [attribute bindings in templates](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/binding-element-attributes/), and this [stack overflow post for extending components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752547/8585664).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I finally resolved the problem by removing this add-on and importing `jquery-ui` and then making the sessions draggable via `jquery-ui` interface.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured out a way forward

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out.